# Favicon is not showing in Github Pages

Tags: github, github-pages, favicon

As the title states, GH pages is not showing my favicon. The favicon does show while doing npm start or through the live server. Below is the link to my site as well as the variations of paths I've tried. I have also updated the build index.html file as well and no dice. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9vw2.png) is a screenshot of what my folder directory looks like.

GH Pages link: https://danielleleslie.github.io/portfolio/

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?" />`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/portfolio/favicon.ico" />`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/portfolio/favicon.ico?" />`

Comment: In the future, please write an actual answer if you want to answer your own question, instead of editing the question to include the answer. You can accept the answer to let people know that this question no longer needs an answer. I've moved your answer from the question into a Community Wiki answer this time around.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's edited question:

> For those who may come across this page, I was able to figure it out.
> I changed the filepath for the favicon to
> "http://localhost:3000/portfolio/favicon.ico" and then redeployed the
> app.